# Button Notification Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

The purpose of the notification is to show a question to the user, and the user has two answer options, "YES" or "NO".

The problem is knowing which button the user has uploaded.

One other thing that I did not intend but that happens, is that the user is redirected to an activity, and I did not want that.

If it clicks one of the buttons it is redirected to MainActivty, and what I intend to do only this action is that mainActivity only receives any information about which button the user has uploaded, in order to make the necessary registrations. My intention is only that the user responds to the question without being redirected to anything.

I leave here the piece of code where all this happens. I hope I have been as explicit as possible, and I wonder if what I have described above is possible.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
                int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent newintent = new Intent(this, Notification_Create.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, newintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
    }
}

public class Notification_Create extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id = extras.getInt("id");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        Intent intentTPC = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentTPC.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0,
                        intentTPC,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Student: ")
                .setContentText("Have work?")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_button);
        mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"YES",resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"NO",resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have two different `PendingIntent` (one for each button) with a different options or requestCode.

Comment: Thanks @litelite I already tried this but I encounter the same problem, as the pendingintent has in one of its parameters has associated an intent, this intent will redirect to an activity ....

Comment: @litelite other question
But regarding the request code how could I do this? Can you help me?